# How to achieve multiple views using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

So I want intro view with 2-3 buttons. Each button tap leads to specific view. I am wondering how can I achieve this using Java Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect job for a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Here is also a small demo from me:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutTutorial {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout demo");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
    JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Switch to second panel/workspace");
    JButton buttonSecond = new JButton("Switch to first panel/workspace");
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CardLayoutTutorial() {
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);

        panelFirst.add(buttonOne);
        panelSecond.add(buttonSecond);
        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        panelCont.add(panelFirst, "1");
        panelCont.add(panelSecond, "2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "2");
            }
        });

        buttonSecond.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });

        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CardLayoutTutorial();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When you click on `buttonOne` view will be switched to `panelSecond` and when you click `buttonSecond` view will be switched to `panelFirst`